# UICollectionView jumps when beginning the scroll when using large title

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've built a test app after seeing this in one of my own apps.
I have a Collection View embedded in a navigation controller.

[image: main.storyboard]

This is all linked up to the ViewController class.

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private let reuseIdentifier = "userCell"
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    let users = Stub.users

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.automaticallyAdjustsScrollIndicatorInsets = false
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    }
}

// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.users.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! UserCollectionViewCell
        cell.setup(user: self.users[indexpath.row])
        return cell
    }
}

// MARK: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let hight = view.frame.height
        let width = view.frame.width

        return CGSize(width: width * 0.3, height: hight * 0.185)
    }
}
```

Everything functionality wise works, however when I scroll, the top of the collection view jumps.
This only happens when I set `prefersLargeTitles` to `true`. Or if I have a search bar in the navigation bar.

[image]

How do you fix this so that is doesn't jump around?
If you have any question please ask.
Thank you.

Comment: What happens when you change: `collectionView.automaticallyAdjustsScrollIndicatorInsets = false`

Comment: The same behiavior persists.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by constraining the `collectionView` to the top of the superview rather than to the `safeArea` top.

May not be a viable solution in every case since your own use case may require it pinned to the `safeArea` but this seems to be the cause anyway.